# SQL join problem

Tags: sql

I would like to count amount of photos for each users albums, all goes right until user has no photo in one album, then (i think) `WHERE ap.del = 0` do that album doesn't appear. Please Help, DB is Postgresql!

```
 SELECT a.id_album, a.id_osoba, a.name, a.description, a.privacy, a.del, a.data_del, a.cover, a.date, count(ap.id_album_photo) AS ilosc
   FROM album a
   LEFT JOIN album_photo ap ON ap.id_album = a.id_album
  WHERE ap.del = 0
  GROUP BY a.id_album, a.id_osoba, a.name, a.description, a.privacy, a.del, a.data_del, a.cover, a.date
  ORDER BY a.name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to show up when there is no album_photo regardless, you could do :

```
WHERE ap.del = 0 OR ap.id_album IS NULL
```

If there is no album_photo, the LEFT JOIN will just return all the album_photo values as NULL. Checking against the join key for NULL will show you that no row was joined in.

Answer (score 1):

Move `WHERE ap.del = 0` to the `JOIN`

`LEFT JOIN album_photo ap ON ap.id_album = a.id_album AND ap.del = 0`

ap.del will be `NULL` when there are no `album_photo`, which means the `WHERE` clause will filter out rows where ap.del is null. As `NULL = 0` is unknown and returns false.

Same thing applies anytime you want to filter on a `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT
    a.id_album,
    a.id_osoba,
    a.name,
    a.description,
    a.privacy,
    a.del,
    a.data_del,
    a.cover,
    a.date,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN ap.id_album_photo IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS liczba
FROM
    album AS a
LEFT JOIN
    album_photo AS ap
ON
    a.id_album = ap.id_album
AND
    ap.del = 0
GROUP BY
    a.id_album,
    a.id_osoba,
    a.name,
    a.description,
    a.privacy,
    a.del,
    a.data_del,
    a.cover,
    a.date
ORDER BY
    a.name;
```

or

```
SELECT
    a.id_album,
    a.id_osoba,
    a.name,
    a.description,
    a.privacy,
    a.del,
    a.data_del,
    a.cover,
    a.date,
    COALESCE(ap.liczba, 0) AS liczba
FROM
    album AS a
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            ap.id_album,
            COUNT(1) AS liczba
        FROM
            album_photo AS ap
        WHERE
            ap.del = 0
        GROUP BY
            ap.id_album
    ) AS ap
ON
    ap.id_album = a.id_album
ORDER BY
    a.name;
```

?